# How I use a "NOT" operator in the ldap filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, active-directory, ldap-query

I use a filter for search a list of user in Active Directory...

Here is my filter example:

AD.filterung = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=*)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*))(l=" + Werk + ")(cn=*))";

It show me all user with UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE but i want show all other User the not Unlock ...how I build a not operator in my filter. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried simply with "!" ?

```
AD.filterung = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=)(|(telephoneNumber=)(mail=))(l=" + Werk + ")(cn=))";
```

Comment: Please be careful with the not operator. It turns out it is hard to optmize for these queries and so the perf can be highly variable depending upon the nature of the query (search results to traverse, state of the db, etc.).